# How let vscode know Drupal's global variable (Drupal.) or files from library.yml

Tags: drupal, visual-studio-code

My Drupal codes are work fine, just want to get more from VSCODE.
After I turned on  "checkJs": true  on jsconfig.json,

VSCODE gives me many problems on status window
but most problems seem VSCODE can't recognize global variable 'Drupal' or 'drupalSettings'

How do I let VSCODE know my drupal's global variables?
and also want to know how VSCODE recognize loaded files from library.yml

erroed js file

```
(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
  // init
  var DFA = Drupal.default_function_ajax;
  var DF = Drupal.default_function;
```

VSCODE ERROR : Property 'default_function_ajax' does not exist on 'typeof Drupal'

and this is library.yml file

```
global-styling:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    dist/js/index.js: {}
    js/default-function-ajax.js: {}
    js/page.js: {}
```

and this is default-function-ajax.js

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.default_function_ajax = {
    load_ajax: function (ajax_url, arg1 = "", arg2 = "") {
....
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I answered my self, but still, don't know what is the reason.
on the last line of .js

```
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

by default, but after I change jQuery only

```
})(jQuery);
```

the problems are gone.
but still, I can't use intellisense of global Drupal and
intellisense method of my custom files like default-function-ajax.js
loaded by library.yml